# after given time call another void

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I want to call another void after given time. My code doesn't work:

```
void Philosopher::think()
{
    auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    cout<<"Philosopher nr: "<<id<<" is thinking"<<endl;
    if (chrono::system_clock::now()-start == think_time)
    {
        starve();
    }

}
```

Comment: Check equality for time is not a good idea, you need that `now()-start` is precisely equal to your think_time, this never happens. Maybe you want to use a `>=` and add a boolean flag to call starve only one time.

Comment: Yeah, just use inequality `>=`

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov , could you show how it would look?

Comment: All depends on frameworks/libraries used. Standard library is a bit clunky for that purpose. For example in `Qt` there is [QTimer::singleShot](https://i.redd.it/7m7pl9kohd371.jpg) in `boost::asio` you can use `boost::asio::deadline_timer` and so on.

Comment: `void` is a type. You can't "call" a `void` - it would be like "calling" an `int` or a `bool`. The word you're looking for is "function".

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell from the context how do you use your function `think()`, there are two possibilities:

- you call it once and expect it to hang on until the current philosopher is done thinking. You can program it like that:

```
void Philosopher::think()
{
    cout<<"Philosopher nr: "<<id<<" is thinking"<<endl;
    while (chrono::system_clock::now()-start < think_time)
    { 
        // do nothing in this loop, just wait
    }
    starve();
}
```

- outside of the code that you've shown you iterate over philosophers and call this method which calls `starve()` for those who've done thinking. For this you can for example make another field in `Philosopher` class with start time of thinking and then repeatedly checking the state of every philosopher:

```
void Philosopher::think()
{
    cout<<"Philosopher nr: "<<id<<" is thinking"<<endl;
    if (chrono::system_clock::now()-this.think_start >= think_time)
    {
        starve();
    }
}

int main() 
{
    // ... some code
    auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    for(auto philosopher : philosophers)
    {
        philosopher.think_start = start  
    }
    while(/* some condition to stop checking philosophers' state */) 
    {
        for(auto philosopher : philosophers)
        {
            philosopher.think()
        }
    }
    
    // ... some code
}
```

Comment: There is no need to load CPU with empty loop. You at least can use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` or some other synchronization mechanisms.